# Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM): How to Handle Background Notifications in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an Android app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for push/receive notifications. I've successfully implemented FCM for handling notifications when the app is in the foreground, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle notifications when the app is in the background.
When I check the onMessageReceived, it does not enter this.
**Manifest**

```
<service
            android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService**

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
            val title = remoteMessage.notification!!.title.toString()
            val body = remoteMessage.notification!!.body.toString()
            val uid = remoteMessage.data["uid"].toString()
            val type = remoteMessage.data["type"].toString() 
            SharePrefUtils.setValueCheck(this, "type", type)
            Log.d(TAG, "type: $type")
        } else {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        }
    }
```

I want to enter onMessageReceived function

Comment: When the push notification has data inside, it will not call the onMessageReceived if the app is  in the background. It will produce a notification to the system tray and you can get the data in the extras of the intent, in the activity that opens the notification. 
Source:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).